# Naming a Row number based on a variable

Tags: excel, vba

By my question, you can conclude that I am new to VBA.
I recorded some macros that basically select some rows and then sort that data in various ways.  One such macro is shown below.  It selects rows 17 through 203 and then sorts by column "AJ" in ascending order.

The problem is that I do not want the last row of my selection, Row 203, to be a constant. I want it to be a variable.  In my spreadsheet, I have a variable in cell Z10 that I want to use as the number to assign to the last row of my sort selection.  For example if the value of Z10 was 100, then I want my macro to select rows 17 through row 100 and perform the sort.  If I put a value of 203 in cell Z10, then I want the macro to sort based on selecting rows 17 through 203, and so on.

Thanks
Pat

```
' Ticker Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    Rows("17:203").Select
    Range("A203").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invest daily").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invest daily").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "AJ17:AJ203"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invest daily").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A17:DB203")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
       .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
   Range("AJ17").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
Dim nLastRowIndex As Long, nColIndex As Long

nLastRowIndex = 203 'TODO determine last row index
nColIndex = 17

'Instead of Rows("17:203").Select, you'll do:    
Rows(CStr(nColIndex) & ":" & CStr(nLastRowIndex)).Select
...
```

The `Dim` statement in VBA declares a variable (here `nLastRowIndex` and `nColIndex`) and then you can assign values to them (203 and 17, respectively). Later on you can use these values to form a cell index by turning the numeric values of the variables into strings and then concatenating them into the cell index `"17:203"`.

If you want to use another cell that will contain the last row number (like `Z10` in your question), all you need to do is something like (untested code, you may have to tweak this a bit but it's close):

```
nLastRowIndex = CLng(Cells("Z10").Value)
```

This code reads the value of cell `Z10`, converts it to a `Long` (32-bit integer value) and then assigns the value to `nLastRowIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the value in the Z10 cell and assign this value to a variable and then, use this variable instead of your constant :

```
' Ticker Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    Dim MaxRow As String
    MaxRow = Cells(10,26).Value
    Rows("17:" & MaxRow).Select
    Range("A" & MaxRow).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invest daily").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invest daily").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "AJ17:AJ" & MaxRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invest daily").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A17:DB" & MaxRow)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
       .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
   Range("AJ17").Select
End Sub
```